# Inverse x axis in the hexbinplot

Tags: r, graphics

Is it possible to reverse x-axis for the hexbinplot?

```
hexbinplot(y~x, xbins=30,xlim = rev(range(x)))
```

The option  `xlim = rev(range(x))` did not work out.

Comment: "thank you" in comments is actually deprecated on SO (although the sentiment is appreciated); if one of these questions is a good (best) answer to your question, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do this with `hexbin::hexbinplot`, but it's pretty easy with `ggplot2`, using `geom_hex` and `scale_x_reverse`.

```
 dd <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000))
 ggplot(dd,aes(x,y))+geom_hex()+scale_x_reverse()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can mulitply the `x` by `-1` to reverse the plot, and then use the `scales` argument to reverse the labels

```
set.seed(1) 
dd <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000))
y = dd$y ; xnew=-dd$x

library(hexbin)
hexbinplot(y ~ xnew, scales=list(x=list(at = pretty(xnew), 
                                        labels = rev(pretty(xnew)))))
```